# SMPlayer started rendering video poorly

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, video, smplayer

Since last update the SMPlayer become unusable. Every video I play (even quite high quality ones in 1080) looks like it is interlaced. When I play same videos in VLC they are fine.

I have tried fiddling with filters (enabling de-interlacing, disabling post-processing entirely and so on), but nothing seems to make any difference.

SMPLayer (or maybe MPV) broke after last update. Current versions:

```
SMPlayer 17.8.0

mpv baead23-amended (C) 2000-2017 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
 built on Sat Aug 12 11:45:31 UTC 2017
ffmpeg library versions:
   libavutil       55.73.100
   libavcodec      57.102.100
   libavformat     57.76.100
   libswscale      4.7.102
   libavfilter     6.98.100
   libswresample   2.8.100
ffmpeg version: git-2017-08-11-7735ed2
```

Edit1: I have just tried same video file running on mpv player directly and it is fine. So the culprit seems to be the SMPlayer.

Edit2: Added a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYZQZ.jpg).

Comment: Maybe take up on smplayer site. A few points. Same mpv & both sm 17.5 & then 17.8 work ok here.  Did you try a new smplayer.ini? (move .config/smplayer to a .bak) You could also just switch smplayer to vlc backend. While mpv does generally work ok in smplayer it, (smplayer) is by no means a supported frontend due to the methods it uses mpv with.

Comment: @doug Thanks for a tip. After temporarily disabling my config it is working, so it is a fault of some option. Unfortunately I don't think I can use any other backend than mpv (I need to change a sound channels matrix and I don't think any other backend supports it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was **hardware decoding** set to **vdpau**. After trying other options several of them are working fine (I don't see a control overlay, but at least the video isn't full of artifacts).

Comment: Are you using nvidia drivers? On my main install I just use Intel but could check in another install where nvidia is used. Not sure how smplayer handles a wrong hwdec setting, mpv itself would just go back to software decoding..

Comment: Yes, I am using (proprietary) nvidia drivers. But the vdpau setting was working quite a long time, like half a year. Software decoding is without artifacts as well, it seems to be something related to vdpau + nvidia.

Comment: Checked here, the install on nvidia drivers works fine. Though I've upgraded to the HWE mesa  (17.0.7) & xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 (2:1.19.3). Additionally because it's an optimus laptop I've enabled Prime Synchronization & all works fine, smooth, no h-tearing.. If you've such hardware take a look here - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365449